# Changing the underlying data associated with a D3 selection?

Tags: d3.js

I have some circles in D3 with data attached to them:

```
var data = [[0,1],[2,10],[3,4],[2,4]]

var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", d[0])
   .attr("cy", d[1])
```

I would like to modify the underlying data bound to these circles to be an array of objects:

```
circles = circles.data().map(function(d) {
  return {x: d[0], y: d[1]}
})
```

How can I change the underlying data associated with a D3 selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:  either modify the data array with the `array.map` function *before* joining it to your elements, or use the [`selection.datum` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum) to modify each data object without changing the data join.  You can't get the original data array back from your selection and modify it.

For the first option, your code would be:

```
var data = [[0,1],[2,10],[3,4],[2,4]];

data = data.map(function(d) {
  return {x: d[0], y: d[1]};
} );

var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d){return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d){return d.y;})
```

For the second option, your code would be:

```
var data = [[0,1],[2,10],[3,4],[2,4]];

var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .datum( function(d) {
      return {x: d[0], y: d[1]};
  } )
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d){return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d){return d.y;})
```

Comment: The third option would be to modify `.__data__` of the selected elements.

Comment: Oh sure, if you *want* to scare the d3 newbies, you could bring that up!  For @turtle, that is essentially what the `.datum()` method does.